# D3 updating a vertical stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a vertical stacked bar chart and want to dynamically remove `rect` elements. To do this I followed the basic enter/update/exit procedure. What happens though is, that the bars seem to be added even if their width = 0;

```
var drawBars = function(data) {
  var margin = {top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5, left: 170},
      width = 1020 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 1820 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      scope = this;

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .rangeRound([0, width-150]);

  var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeBands([0,height], .2, 3);

  var color = d3.scale.category20c();

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("top")
      .tickSize(0)
      .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .tickSize(0)
      .orient("left");

  var svg = d3.select('#barchart svg')
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var createData = function(filter) {
    var data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.org; })
      .key(function(d){ return d.taskforce_id })
      .rollup(function(v){ return v.length })
      .entries(scope.rawData['participants']);

      _.each(data, d => {
          _.extend(d, _.object(_.map(d.values, c => {
            if (typeof filter !== 'undefined') {
              if (c.key == filter) {
                return [c.key, c.values];
              }
              return [c.key, 0];
            }
            return [c.key, c.values];
          })));
          delete d.values;
      });

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      var y0 = 0;
      d.orgs = ["A", "B", "C"].map(function(org) {
        if (d[org] === undefined) {
          return {name: org, y0: 0, y1: 0};
        } else {
          return {name: org, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[org]};
        }

      });
      d.total = d3.max(d.orgs, d => { return d.y1; });
    });

    data.sort(function(x, y){
       return d3.descending(x.total, y.total);
    });
    return data;
  };

  var redrawChart = function(filter) {
    var data = createData(filter);
    console.log(data);

    x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "key"; }));

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 15 + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

    /////////
      //ENTER//
      /////////
    var chartRow = svg.selectAll("g.chartRow")
      .data(data);

    var newRow = chartRow
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "chartRow")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0, " + y(d.key) + ")"; });

    var rectRow = newRow.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(function(d) { return d.orgs; });

    rectRow
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "bar t_"+ d.name; } )
      .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
      .on('click', function(d){
        redrawChart(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

    //////////
      //UPDATE//
      //////////
    chartRow.selectAll('rect').transition()
      .duration(300)
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.y1) - x(d.y0); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.y0); })
      .attr("opacity",1);

      ////////
      //EXIT//
      ////////
    chartRow.exit().selectAll("rect.bar").transition()
      .style("opacity","0")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + ")")
      .remove();
  };

  redrawChart();

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse());

  var legends = legend.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 25 + ")"; });

  legend.exit().remove();

  legends.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 28)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legends.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 34)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  legends.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 14)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("class", "numbers")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

};
```

When I `console.log` the `data` everything seems ok, so the filtering works. However, the widths of the `rect` elements seem to use the OLD data set. Equally, the legends and axis are being duplicated

**Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/4nm44fgt/**

Any insights?

Comment: We don't know how the data changes but from the code, the rectRow selection gets its data from d.orgs. You should do the same for the update chartRow selection

Comment: You posted a lot of code, but yet there are a lot of things, from scales to function calls, that we have to guess. Why don't you post a MCVE? A fiddle/pen/plunker, for instance?

Comment: Good point, just added a fiddle

Comment: Even if the width is 0 d3.exit will not remove it. d3 exit only removes when the bar's data is removed from the array. Regarding axis it gets duplicated because your are appending the axis again in the `redrawChart` here is a fiddle with some fixes https://jsfiddle.net/4nm44fgt/

Comment: @Cyril your fiddle shows no difference?

Comment: I am sorry this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b0jLe0km/ like i said above it fixes the axis issue of over write

Answer (score 0):

Your second data bind should not use only the entering nodes, as after filtering this selection will be empty:

```
 var rectRow = chartRow.selectAll(".bar").data(function(d) {
     return d.orgs;
 });
```

instead of `newRow.selectAll(".bar")...`